# How to stop writing log4j entries after log file reaches certain amount of size

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to change the default behavior of log4j to stop writing log entries to a file when the log file reaches certain amount of size. For example : if the size of log file reaches 100 MB then I don’t want to write any more logs even rolling option should be disabled.

The following is the log4j configurations. Could someone help me, please.

```
log4j.appender.A4=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A4.File=/logs/app/dashboard.log
log4j.appender.A4.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.A4.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.A4.layout=com.util.logging.FilteringLayout
log4j.appender.A4.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n%n
log4j.appender.A4.Append=false
log4j.additivity.A4=true
log4j.logger.com.sample=WARN, A4
```

Thanks & Regards

Jai.

Comment: I would write your own appender that derives from AppenderSkeleton, or some concrete appender. Make it so that it checks the size of the file when it writes the log message, and just no-op it under the conditions you require. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html

Comment: by doing so , you are essentially losing logging information or do you want to overwrite the data in the file once it reaches a limit?

Comment: Mark W,

Thank you for suggestion. I have done this by creating a new custom appender.

Comment: Sam - I don’t want to overwrite once it reaches a limit rather I need to stop logging once it reaches a limit.
Thanks for your time.